# Are postnominal adjectives part of the noun phrase?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, adjectives

It is well-known that attributive adjectives constitute part of the same noun phrase in which they occur, and that predicative adjectives are part of a complement.

**My question:**

Are postnominal, or postpositive, adjectives (as in the examples below) considered part of the noun phrase or of a complement?

Examples:

> Let's paint the *kitchen* **yellow**.
>
> They considered *Stuart* **mad**.
>
> The *Secretary* **General** of the United Nations has called for new peace talks.
>
> *Anyone* **intelligent** can do it.
>
> *The house* **ablaze** is next door to mine.
>
> We are looking for *people* **skilled in design**.

Comment: There are multiple structures here. In "Let's paint the kitchen yellow", "yellow" is an [object complement](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/object_complement.htm). In a phrase like "Secretary General", you have a [postnominal adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective). "ablaze" is a reduced relative clause, but still part of the noun phrase "The house ablaze".

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. Does this mean that postnominal adjectives can be in some cases part of the noun phrase, and in others part of the complement?